# Why is this class property not being modified in PHP?

Tags: php, function, oop

I have this function:

```
public userID = 1;

public function setID($id)
    {
        $this->userID = $id;

    }
```

It's located in a class so this function should set the userID variable on the top. As you can see here I create an object and call the function with the correct parameter:

```
$data = new Data();
$data->setID(($_SESSION['ID']));
```

The session ID is indeed available to use I echo'd the session ID.

But now I have another function to use the userID variable and then i get the error:

> Undefined variable: userID.

The function I use this variable is this one:

```
$ordSql = "INSERT INTO order(DATUM, KLANT_ID) VALUES($datum, $userID)";
$resultaat = mysqli_query($verbinding, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
```

This is in another function below my setID function. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: Yes, I have this in another document which is included. I also said this in my post.

Comment: If you have an error on a function using the userID, you should show us this function

Comment: I'll do that one moment

Comment: Have you try `$data->userID` to get value of userID

Comment: That will not work because there is another function in this class which needs the variable so I don't think i need an object to get the public variable

Comment: `public userID` that's being treated as a constant. Error reporting would have signaled that.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the $ on your public $userId variable. This example prints 42:

```php
<?php

class Data {
    public $userId = 1;

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->userId = $id;
    }

    public function otherFunction() {
        echo $this->userId;
    }
}

$data = new Data();
$data->setId(42);
$data->otherFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $userID;
```

to

```
$this->userID;
```

Comment: I mistyped that when adding this code to stack im sorry

Comment: @user1743508: if the question as it stands is not an accurate reflection of what you have, please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $this->userID instead of $userID

```
$ordSql = "INSERT INTO order(DATUM, KLANT_ID) VALUES($datum, $this->userID )";
$resultaat = mysqli_query($verbinding, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
```

Answer (score 0):

It was posted but deleted again this is the solution :

```
$ordSql = "INSERT INTO order(DATUM, KLANT_ID) VALUES($datum, $this->userID)";
$resultaat = mysqli_query($verbinding, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
```

instead of :

```
$ordSql = "INSERT INTO order(DATUM, KLANT_ID) VALUES($datum, $userID)";
$resultaat = mysqli_query($verbinding, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($verbinding));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, the variable `$usedID` is not set. The **property** `userId` is set though.

You are trying to use a property of the class as a variable, which is not possible. (You may have another variable named $userID, it's quite common in setters for example)

You should always use`$this->userId` and not `$userID`.